# Dynamically assigned table variables?

Tags: variables, lua, lua-table

Writing a function in Lua, which creates two tables. I want the tables to be assigned to the value name with an x added, and one with a y added. For example if name was line, it would create two tables linex and liney, but I can't figure out how to do it. The following obviously doesn't work (and is just for display purposes) but how would I go about doing this?

```
function makelinep(x,y,minrand,maxrand,name,length)
  name..x = {}
  name..y = {}
```

Later I hope to access "linex" and "liney" after values have been written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want these in the global name space you would use

```
_G[name..'x']={}
_G[name..'y']={}
```

For a module you'd use `_M` in place of `_G`.

Comment: That works perfectly, I seem to have trouble inserting values into the table though, how would go about doing this? (In the same function)    table.insert(name.."x",count,x)

Doesn't work.

Thank you :D

Comment: name.."x" is not a table but just a string with a name of your table. As in above example _G[name..'x'] is the table so the right syntax is table.insert(_G[name..'x'],count,x)

Comment: Nowadays (5.2, 2011), `_ENV` might be more appropriate than `_G` or `_M`.